# Cocoapods is failing to download dependencies(APPLE M1) in the time of react-native development set up

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, setup-project, apple-m1

This is the screenshot of the current situation. Its a Brand new Apple M1 MacBook. react is working fine but React-native is not getting installed properly. Tried various solutions but no luck.

Comment: There is no screenshot nor error copy-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

First install node, watchman, cocoapods using brew.

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
brew install cocoapods
```

If the machine is M1,

```
sudo gem update --system
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

then you should be able to work using react-native apps.
If you are getting cocoapods error while creating react-native app using,

```
npx react-native init app-name
```

you can go to the app-name/ios and install cocoapods there by,

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

You should have Xcode Command Line Tools beforehand.
And check whether the simulator can be used with Xcode by,

```
xcrun -k --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
```

If it is showing errors,

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

to fix it.